# Where does move_uploaded_file store the file?

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload an file through a web form. The script outputs the following, and there are no errors. Still I can not find the directory on the server. Am I specifying the location wrong? I already tried /upload and the full path that I see in my ftp client: /cygdrive/i/home/antor/dance/upload

```
   Upload: 1.jpg
    Type: image/jpeg
    Size: 107.9072265625 kB
    Stored in: C:\WINDOWS\Temp\php767.tmpUpload: 1.jpg
    Type: image/jpeg
    Size: 107.9072265625 kB
    Temp file: C:\WINDOWS\Temp\php767.tmpStored in: upload/1.jpgUpload: 1.jpg
    Type: image/jpeg
    Size: 107.9072265625 kB
    Temp file: C:\WINDOWS\Temp\php767.tmp
    Stored in: /cygdrive/i/home/antor/dance/upload/1.jpg
```

This is the code I used:

```
    <form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

and:

```
    <?php
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
      {
      echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
      echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
      echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
      echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
      }
      $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
      {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        }
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";
      }


      $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
      {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
          {
          echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
          }
        }
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";
      }

    ?>
```

The folder upload is below the main uploader.php file and has 777 permissions.
Any idea where the file is stored? Or better yet, how I can put it in the right directory.

--UPDATE
The update/ folder seems to be the right position. Still the file does not appear, I tried it on a different server as well. Am I doing something wrong in the script? Is there some extra error check I could do?

Could the .htaccess have anything to do with it? There is a drupal site on the level above dance, which has .htaccess:

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|svn-base)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|all-wcprops|entries|format)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Force simple error message for requests for non-existent favicon.ico.
<Files favicon.ico>
  # There is no end quote below, for compatibility with Apache 1.3.
  ErrorDocument 404 "The requested file favicon.ico was not found.
</Files>

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Override PHP settings. More in sites/default/settings.php
# but the following cannot be changed at runtime.

# PHP 4, Apache 1.
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# PHP 4, Apache 2.
<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value magic_quotes_gpc                0
  php_value register_globals                0
  php_value session.auto_start              0
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_value mbstring.encoding_translation   0
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  # Do not cache dynamically generated pages.
  ExpiresByType text/html A1
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # adapt and uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment and adapt the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# $Id: .htaccess,v 1.90.2.3 2008/12/10 20:04:08 goba Exp $
```

Comment: Your code is storing the data in Temp, and the moving it to a upload folder. I would recommend using 755

Comment: they have 755 permissions now, no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the folder is below the .php file, then

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

is trying to upload it to an 'upload' directory on the same level as the file your running this from.

try

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: That seems to make sense. Yet, I tried it and still no file. I did notice the permissions jumped back to 755, but as I am listed as the owner I think that's ok. Any way I could check for errors during the move?

Comment: I'd put a file in there called testfile.php, then from that script if (file_exists("upload/testfile.php")) {echo 'correct path';}else {echo 'Incorrect Path';} , that will tell you if the path is correct. If it is then you've narrowed down your search - try 777 permissions aswell as if the file is created by apache it may well not belong to you, if that works then you know it's permissions and you can adjust to one that's more secure and also allows you to write

Comment: It says correct path. I can't change the permissions to 777, they always default to 755, don't have total control over the webserver. At least I know it's just "upload/", but why isn't the file appearing?

Comment: have you checked to see if the files HAVE been uploaded, and just aren't appearing in FTP? upload a file via your form, and then check if that file exists with the same method I mentioned above. Often they won't appear in FTP straight away.

Comment: Tried that, the file is not there.

Comment: The server automatically rechanges the permissions to 755. The system admin once created a 777 folder for me, so I tried uploading in that and it works ../sites/default/files/dance/

Answer (score 2):

You missed enctype property of form. Add this to your form tag

```
enctype='multipart/form-data'
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file info.php and put the following contents in it.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Upload it on your server where your upload script is, open in your browser and find:

```
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]
```

This will show you full path to file and helps to find out path to your upload folder.

Correct path would be:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "I:\home\antor\dance\upload\\" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: Ok, that outputs "I:\home\antor\dance\upload\", so it would appear to be a windows's server. Putting this as the path messes everything up due to the \ instead of / move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "I:\home\antor\dance\upload\\" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

Comment: Also tried antor/dance/upload/, but that did not do it. Perhaps there is an error somewhere else, and it is not the moving?

Comment: Just add one more slash. Correct would be: move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "I:\home\antor\dance\upload\\" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

Comment: Thanks, but I think that's what I wrote

Comment: Copy/paste it and see does it work. \ did you have additional slash at end?

Comment: Thanks, still doesn't work. Beginning to suspect it's not just the folder-name

Answer (score 0):

lets say you run http://somelink.com/app/upload.php then upload folder will be under /app/upload only

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to create an upload directory in your source or home directory

Comment: the upload directory is created and is under my home/antor/dance